# Compare Two Dynamic String Arrays

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm looking for a little guidance and experience. I have an VBA module that creates two strings. See below. I want to use an array to compare the two stings and write the successful matches or "no match" for the element to a third array or directly to the worksheet.
The second part of this is a "percent of" match of Arr2 to Arr1. So the below example would be 88%.

```
> Arr1 result  
> 726741,439037,X41033X,X0254XX,X47083X,X0252XX,X50047X,XH5815X
> Arr2 result
> 726742,439037,X41033X,X0254XX,X47083X,X0252XX,X50047X,XH5815X
```

Any advice would be great.

Comment: What have you tried for comparing the arrays so far? If you made [collections](http://www.herongyang.com/ASP/VBScript-Collection-Class.html) instead then you can use the `.Item()` to test if a value exists. There are better links but that one would get you started for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim str1 As String, str2 As String
    Dim arr, i As Long, cnt As Long

    str1 = "726741,439037,X41033X,X0254XX,X47083X,X0252XX,X50047X,XH5815X"
    str2 = "726742,439037,X41033X,X0254XX,X47083X,X0252XX,X50047X,XH5815X"

    For i = LBound(Split(str1, ",")) To UBound(Split(str1, ","))
        If Not IsArray(arr) Then
            arr = Array(IIf(Split(str1, ",")(i) = _
                Split(str2, ",")(i), "Match", "NoMatch"))
        Else
            ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
            arr(UBound(arr)) = IIf(Split(str1, ",")(i) = _
                Split(str2, ",")(i), "Match", "NoMatch")
        End If
    Next

    '~~> Check the array
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print arr(i)
        If arr(i) = "Match" Then cnt = cnt + 1
    Next
    '~~> output the percentage
    MsgBox Format(cnt / (UBound(arr) + 1), "0.00%")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response PortlandRunner and L42. I didn't think to split the array. Both your solutions should get me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to accomplish the task using simple for loops.

```
Sub compareStrings()
    Dim str1 As String
    Dim str2 As String
    str1 = "726741,439037,X41033X,X0254XX,X47083X,X0252XX,X50047X,XH5815X"
    str2 = "726742,439037,X41033X,X0254XX,X47083X,X0252XX,X50047X,XH5815X"

    Dim Arr1 As Variant
    Dim Arr2 As Variant
    Dim ArrResults As Variant

    Arr1 = Split(str1, ",")
    Arr2 = Split(str2, ",")

    Dim countMatches As Integer
    countMatches = 0

    ReDim ArrResults(UBound(Arr1))

    For i = LBound(Arr1) To UBound(Arr1)
        If Arr1(i) = Arr2(i) Then
            ArrResults(i) = "Matches"
            countMatches = countMatches + 1
        Else
            ArrResults(i) = "No Match"
        End If
    Next i

    'Print out the results array in debug window
    For Each entry In ArrResults
        Debug.Print entry
    Next entry

    Dim ratio As Double
    ratio = countMatches / (UBound(Arr1) + 1)

    MsgBox (ratio * 100 & "%")
End Sub
```

---

Message box will display this:

[image]

---

Immediate window will display the results array values like this:

[image]